# Spark submit (2.3) on kubernetes cluster from Python

Tags: python, apache-spark, kubernetes, aws-lambda

So now that k8s is integrated directly with spark in 2.3 my spark submit from the console executes correctly on a kuberenetes master without any spark master pods running, spark handles all the k8s details:

```
spark-submit \
  --deploy-mode cluster \
  --class com.app.myApp \
  --master k8s://https://myCluster.com \
  --conf spark.kubernetes.authenticate.driver.serviceAccountName=spark \
  --conf spark.app.name=myApp \
  --conf spark.executor.instances=10 \
  --conf spark.kubernetes.container.image=myImage \
  local:///myJar.jar
```

What I am trying to do is do a spark-submit via AWS lambda to my k8s cluster. Previously I used the command via the spark master REST API directly (without kubernetes):

```
request = requests.Request(
    'POST',
    "http://<master-ip>:6066/v1/submissions/create",
    data=json.dumps(parameters))
prepared = request.prepare()
session = requests.Session()
response = session.send(prepared)
```

And it worked. Now I want to integrate Kubernetes and do it similarly where I submit an API request to my kubernetes cluster from python and have spark handle all the k8s details, ideally something like:

```
request = requests.Request(
    'POST',
    "k8s://https://myK8scluster.com:443",
    data=json.dumps(parameters))
```

Is it possible in the Spark 2.3/Kubernetes integration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I afraid that is impossible for Spark 2.3, if you using native Kubernetes support.

Based on description from [deployment instruction](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-kubernetes.html), submission process container several steps:

1. Spark creates a Spark driver running within a Kubernetes pod.
2. The driver creates executors which are also running within Kubernetes pods and connects to them, and executes application code.
3. When the application completes, the executor pods terminate and are cleaned up, but the driver pod persists logs and remains in “completed” state in the Kubernetes API until it’s eventually garbage collected or manually cleaned up.

So, in fact, you have no place to submit a job until you starting a submission process, which will launch a first Spark's pod (driver) for you. And after application completes, everything terminated.

Because of running a fat container on AWS Lambda is not a best solution, and also because if is not way to run any commands in container itself (is is possible, but with hack, here is [blueprint](https://github.com/jacov/lambda-bash) about executing Bash inside an AWS Lambda) the simplest way is to write some small custom service, which will work on machine outside of AWS Lambda and provide REST interface between your application and `spark-submit` utility. I don't see any other ways to make it without a pain.

Comment: In this case, `--master` is a k8s master only. There is no spark master actively running on the cluster, will this still work?

Comment: You right, @amza, I updated an answer. With native Kubernetes we have no Spark master.

Comment: @Anton Kostenko So there is no way I can use aws lambda for spark job submissions in 2.3 , I would need aws lambda because of event triggers (cron expression , file based trigger) ie I need to spark-submit a spark application  based on either a cron expression or file trigger .please suggest

Comment: If you can get events about file changed (as example, from S3 or from somewhere else which support it) then use trigger. If that is a complex or custom solution - I think cron will be more stable.

Comment: Sorry my question is I need to spark submit a spark application on k8 cluster using Aws lambda (as it supports both s3 file trigger and cron) but how can I spark-submit from aws lambda without rest interface? I see you mentioned a hack but I didn’t completely get that how to use to spark-submit on k8 master.

Comment: @Anton Kostenko

Comment: As I mentioned, it is hard to run `spark-submit` directly on AWS Lambda, but, you can use Labda to call your custom service (actually I think you can write in in 1 hour) which will provide you interface between REST and `spark-submit` and will be deployed to some VM outside of Lambda. So flow will be like Event -(running by trigger)-> AWS Lambda -(call your service by REST)-> Custom service -(running spark-submit)->Profit:). Using that flow you can use AWS Lambda for everything like before, just will call Spark thru your custom service instead of call Spark directly.

Comment: You mean I run that custom service in a pod in the same k8 cluster and expose it as a rest service and access it from lambda ? I’m just worried about the scalability of the custom service pod as I will have multiple job submissions will be executed on lambda parallely,maybe I will need to have good number of replicas of the custom service pod to start with

Comment: I guess the custom service should be part of k8 cluster how can it spark-submit if it resides on a separate VM outside k8 cluster.Correct me if I’m wrong

Comment: @Anton Kostenko

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167263/discussion-between-shiv455-and-anton-kostenko).